# 2 Dropdowns, 1 object ids, other with lists from lists in objects

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, asp.net-web-api

I've got two multiselect dropdowns on a page that uses angularJS.  The first is populated from a service call which returns a lists of objects which are basically category objects. The second dropdown is a list of all the specifics from all those categories.  Let's call them Groups and Items for simplicity.  Originally, I just populated the second list with a second api call which returned a list of those Items.  But since the Group objects already contain a list of the Items which are related, this seems unnecessary.  (And I'd like to be able to tie the two together, so that if a group is selected, only the items which fall into that group are displayed in the second dropdown, but that's secondary...) My first dropdown get's populated with this code:

```
    $scope.promiseGetGroupNames = providerContactInfoService.getGroupNames();
    $scope.promiseGetGroupNames.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.GroupDDLdata = pl.data;
        }, function (errorPl) {
            //error message...
        });
```

So I would assume that in there I could loop through the data and generate a list there, but it seems like angular would have a simpler way of doing things... Is there a way that I can set the options of the second dropdown to be a complete list of items from all of the groups in the first, and then when a user selects one of those groups, remove all but the items which fall into that category?

Additionally, I have researched this, and found some answers that looked like there was a way to connect the ng-options of 2nd dropdown to the ng-model of the first, which seems like what I want to do, at least for the 2nd half, but I still need to get all options in there at page load...

The other idea I had was to simply make two service calls... the first pulls all of the possible items, the 2nd would pull a subset that only falls into the group select... since only one group is ever allowed to be selected, it's not terribly inefficient, but if the person selects one group, then a different one... seems like that would all be unnecessary if it's possible to link all the objects/options/models together...

What is the best practice for this type of scenario, and if it's the first, could someone explain a little about how to set up that connection?  I understand the basics of pulling the possible options from the model, but not exactly sure on the syntax (I'm relatively new to angularJS.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

1) Populate your first dropdown list :

```
<select ng-options="groups" ng-model="selectedGroup">

$scope.init = function () {
    service.getGroups.then(function (groups) {
        $scope.groups = groups;
    });
};

$scope.init();
```

2) Use ng-change directive on your first dropdown list :

```
<select ng-options="groups" ng-change="fillSecondList()" ng-model="selectedGroup">

<select ng-options="secondList" ng-model="selectedThing">

$scope.fillSecondList = function () {
    // Whatever you want, you can use $scope.selectedGroup here    
    $scope.secondList = ...
};
```

`$scope.fillSecondList` will fire when your selection changes so you can update `$scope.secondList` according to what's selected in your first list (`$scope.selectedGroup`), for example using a service call using `selectedGroup`as a parameter.

EDIT :

If all your needed data is fetched from the first service call, you can use a filter, as you don't actually need to modify your `secondList` model but rather change what is displayed in your second list.

```
$scope.init = function () {
        service.getGroups.then(function (groups) {
            $scope.groups = groups;
            // Extract the second list from the first one
            $scope.secondList = groups.doSomething();
        });
    };

<select ng-options="secondList | filter: { group : selectedGroup.id }" ng-model="selectedThing">
```

For example, this will display only `secondList` items which have a `group` property equal to `selectedGroup.id`.

You can use a custom filter if your filtering is more complicated, or a filter function in your controller (triggered with ng-change) if you don't plan to re-use this filter anywhere else :

```
$scope.filterSecondList = function () {
    $scope.secondList = $scope.secondList.filter(function (item) {
        return item.group === $scope.selectedGroup.id;
    });
};
```

Comment: This is why I was asking about best practices... I can totally see how to do things this way- in fact since I originally developed the dd's independent of one another, 90% of the coding would already be done... but it seems like if I already have all the information at the angular level, that I should be able to do it all in the controller... even if it's as basic as looping through the objects in the 1st model, and if it's empty, looping through all the objects in the options of the 1st dropdown...

Comment: If you mean that your second list can be sort of computed out of your first one, you can use a filter, check my edit